# oval shape in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm trying to create Oval shape by using `Radius.circular` but it looks like circular shape and I have also tried to change `Radius.elliptical` but still getting a different shape.

```
  Expanded(
            flex: 13,
            child:  Container(
              height: 100,
              width:100,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40,left: 40,right: 40),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: MyColors.colorPrimary,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.0),
                borderRadius:
                new BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(90,45)),
              ),
              child: Text('     '),
            ),
```

I want this

[image]

but getting this

[image]

Comment: what params you used with `Radius.elliptical`?

Comment: @pskink x and y coordinate

Comment: what radii values did you pass to `Radius.elliptical` constructor?

Comment: randomly tried and getting  slightly edged

Comment: `new BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(90,45)),`

Comment: if you have  `width:65` so how come you can have x-radii == 90?

Comment: You are right, I have tried randomly and started with less value than the width and I increase width still getting the same situation

Comment: post your code then

Comment: update code with image

Comment: `Container(
  height: 200,
  color: Colors.blueGrey,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Container(
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 50)),
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
  ),
),`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I assume you are using a `Column` or `Row` widget as parent and using `Expanded` your child is trying to expand to the horizontal.

Add an `Align` or `Center` widget as a parent of your `Container` and it should work:

```
    Align(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 100,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 40, right: 40),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.0),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(100, 50)),
              ),
              child: Text('     '),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Can you give some more info on why this solved the problem?

Comment: @Wecherowski I don't think the Align is what fixed the problem, but the input values for Radius.elliptical. I was able to fix it by changing the elliptical to Radius.elliptical(360, 180)

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution without code migration is

`border: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0.0),`